# blank output, error with scanner/jvm?

Tags: java, printing, jvm

I rechecked this code tons of times and am pretty sure there isn't anything wrong with it, I thought theres a problem with scanner or return statement but even though I changed it still the problem persists. can anyone pleeease point out my flaw is it the scanner im goin nuts. the output is showing blank is my jvm spoilt

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class draft {

int num;
int num2;
int result;
int multiplier;




draft(int set){
    this.multiplier = set;

};


public void question(){
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of choice: ");
int a = kb.nextInt();
this.num = a;
System.out.println("Enter number 2: ");
int b = kb.nextInt();
this.num2 = b;
}
public void multiply(){
    result = num * multiplier + num2 * multiplier;
System.out.print(result);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

        draft aaa = new draft(5);
        aaa.question();
        aaa.multiply();

}

}
```

Comment: What are you expecting? Are you typing into the input when prompted?

Comment: Its working fine.plz provide correcrt int input

Comment: it doesn't show the prompt "Enter number of choice: ", just blank, and doesn't allow me to enter anything so I suspect the scanner isn't working too

Comment: Not sure.. did u try bufferedreader

Comment: no, how do I implement that in my code??

Comment: For Scanner use:   BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in)); and parse the readLine to integer like: int a = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine()); ... and catch the exceptions.  ... But your program works fine.

Comment: Your code works fine, nothing is broken. Suspect your terminal/console input (thats running the program) has an issue rather than the program itself.

Answer (score -1):

You must add your numbers, click under "Enter number of choice" and add number:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Draft g = new Draft(2);
    g.question();
    g.multiply();
}
```

Consol:
Enter number of choice: 
4
Enter number 2: 
2
12

Comment: Yes but i show him only the main and explain how he must add the number ... no reason for down vote!

Comment: only have used jvm for jsp, tomcat servlets and connecting to jdbc for past month since everything was working. I suspect there might be some directory problem etc..